# pyAudio - stop recording at will from command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyaudio

I'm not really that good with Python. Recently I've been toying around with pyAudio and using a simple script managed to record system sound. Thing is, the script I'm using is ran using a fixed timer. Instead, I want to end the recording whenever I want, from command line.

Does anyone know how to achieve this, if possible at all?

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

DURATION = int(sys.argv[1])
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = DURATION
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"
print("hello")

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("Recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print("Finished recording") 

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()
```

Comment: Can you post also a fragment of  your code

Comment: @Cyberguille edited main post